# AWS: How to duplicate UDP traffic from PRD to TEST environment?

Tags: linux, redirect, udp

We have test environment set up on AWS and now we'd like to duplicate the incoming UDP traffic from our production machine to the test environment to see how it works with real data.

Our devices send messages to the listener running on our production machine on specific port (we can't change the port). We have set up the same listener running in test environment, so we just need to duplicate the traffic to it.
There is no need to spoof sender's ip to the test environment (listener is not going to send any data back).

We thought this was a very common thing to do, but it's not so easy to find any nice solution.
We tried to run program called Samplicate on production, but when using it we have to run the listener on different port and then run Samplicate on that port instead, redirecting the traffic both to the production and AWS. It's very dangerous, because if Samplicate fails for some reason (We are not sure it's reliable enough), redirect fails and listener will not be fed so the system will break. It would be much better if the solution didn't have to listen on real ports the devices send messages to. So even if duplication fails for some reason, system continues working 
And anyway we couldn't get Samplicate working even in this way (we did receive the data but the system was not working very well. Maybe Samplicate was damaging packets or we just didn't set it up correctly).

Could anyone advice anything? Is it really something very uncommon and hard to implement?

P.S. We've seen some examples how to do something like this in local network, but we need to duplicate the traffic to different host (AWS)..

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Does your test and production environment have same IPs? If so you can capture packets using tcpdump, copy the pcap file and replay it using tcpreplay

Comment: No, production is on our local server and TEST environment is on Amazon Web-Services. So they  have different IP. Maybe we should consider setting up VPN between them..

Comment: I guess you can manipulate the pcap file and change the IPs. Look here: http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/tcprewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been solved now.
We've found that it's much easier just to write our own sniffer in C and send UDP packets directly to test environment.
We used libcap library to achieve this.

This way the traffic is not interrupted and the production is not under risk.

http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-c-linux/
this link helped a lot.